# _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:0.0" matplotlib bash on windows

Tags: windows, bash, python3, xming, matplotlib

Insipired by the problems with displaying matplotlib used in a Python script using the terminal of the Bash (Ubuntu) on Windows, I have followed [the instructions listed in the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397162/show-matplotlib-plots-in-ubuntu-windows-subsystem-for-linux). However, after restarting the computer, suddenly I get an error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:0.0"
```

Do you have any idea how to fix it and display images?

Citing the mentioned post, I have:

1. Downloaded and installed Xming
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk`
4. (installed matplotlib earlier)
5. `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` and added to ~/.bashrc

Comment: Please [edit] your question to say what you did. The link should be for reference only.

Comment: Answer by @Inyoka on a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988054/tkinter-couldnt-connect-to-display-0) might help

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to open the Xming application on Windows before running the script in the Ubuntu subsystem.